# Store values of integration from array, then use that new array

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm new to Python so I'm really struggling with this. I want to define a function, have a certain calculation done to it for an array of different values, store those newly calculated values in a new array, and then use those new values in another calculation. My attempt is this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

radii = np.arange(10) #array of radius values

def rho(r): 
    return (r**2) 

for i in range(len(radii)):
    def M[r]: #new array by integrating over values from 0 to radii
        scipy.integrate.quad(rho(r), 0, radii[i])

def P(r):
    return (5*M[r]) #make new array using values from M[r] calculated above
```

Comment: Why are you defining a function in a loop? Why do you never call any function?

Comment: @DTRHJ, try the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging. Here in StackOverflow we collaborators expect: (a) a scenario; (b) a given input; (c) a desired output; (d) code that try do result the output; (e) the wrong output or errors; (f) if any, some insights on the wrong result. You gave us half a scenario, and a non-sensical code. Could you do better? Try discussing it with the rubber duck first.

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu I am new to the platform and was not aware of the requirements/standards until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this script is a bit of a mess, so let's unpack this. I've never used `scipy.integrate.quad` but I looked it up, and along with testing it have determined that those are valid arguments for `quad`. There are more efficient ways to do this, but in the interests of preservation, I'll try to keep the overall structure of your script, just fixing the bugs and errors. So, as I understand it, you want to write this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

# Here's where we start to make changes. First, we're going to define the function, taking in two parameters, r and the array radii.
# We don't need to specify data types, because Python is a strongly-typed language.
# It is good practice to define your functions before the start of the program.
def M(r, radii):
    # The loop goes _inside_ the function, otherwise we're just defining the function M(r) over and over again to a slightly different thing!
    for i in range(len(radii)):
        # Also note: since we imported quad from scipy.integrate, we only need to reference quad, and in fact referencing scipy.integrate.quad just causes an error!
        output[i] = quad(r, 0, radii[i])
        # We can also multiply by 5 in this function, so we really only need one. Hell, we don't actually _need_ a function at all,
        # unless you're planning to reference it multiple times in other parts of a larger program.
        output[i] *= 5
    return output

# You have a choice between doing the maths _inside_ the main function or in maybe in a lambda function like this, which is a bit more pythonic than a 1-line normal function. Use like so:
rho = lambda r: r**2 

# Beginning of program (this is my example of what calling the function with a list called radii might be)
radii = np.arange(10)

new_array = M(rho, radii)
```

If this solution is correct, please mark it as accepted.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, I know it's a terrible script, that's why I needed help. I am indeed trying to learn proper syntax but it is a slow process for me, and of course I tried googling other solutions. You state: "unless you're planning to reference it multiple times in other parts of a larger program", I do need to reference it multiple times later and eventually do another integral of it and another function. That is why I wanted to define it as a new function with those stored values.

Comment: So, does my proposed answer work for you? I've given an example of what it might look like to call the function at the bottom of the script.

Comment: @DTRHJ you can call the function as many times as you like using `M(argument_1, argument_2)` as I demonstrated in the last line of the script. Also, in Python we generally just refer to arrays (especially 1-dimensional arrays) as lists, so you might get more answers on your next question by calling them by their more Pythonic name.

Comment: @Thamespython, kudos! Man, I would not have the patience!

Comment: @Thamespython yes, thanks. It's marked solved.